# How to concatenate items of n arrays which use custom dtype in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, dtype

I have a custom dtype defined as:

```
myType = np.dtype([
    ('foo', 'u4'),
    ('bar', 'f8')
])
```

I define n vectors of this custom dtype (in this example just two):

```
a=np.array([(2, 1.1), (3, 2.2)], dtype=myType)
b=np.array([(4, 3.3), (5, 4.4), (6, 5.5)], dtype=myType)
print(np.shape(a))
print(np.shape(b))
```

I group the n vectors in a python list:

```
data = [a,b]   # Will be n vectors, not just two
```

I want to join the two vectors so I would get a vector c, same as if I do:

```
c=np.array([(2, 1.1), (3, 2.2), (4, 3.3), (5, 4.4), (6, 5.5)], dtype=myType)
print(np.shape(c))
c
```

I try:

```
np.vstack(data)
```

But I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-f65a6d8e700e> in <module>
----> 1 np.vstack(data)

<__array_function__ internals> in vstack(*args, **kwargs)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py in vstack(tup)
    281     if not isinstance(arrs, list):
    282         arrs = [arrs]
--> 283     return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
    284 
    285 

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 2 and the array at index 1 has size 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [49]: a=np.array([(2, 1.1), (3, 2.2)], dtype=myType)
    ...: b=np.array([(4, 3.3), (5, 4.4), (6, 5.5)], dtype=myType)
In [50]: a
Out[50]: array([(2, 1.1), (3, 2.2)], dtype=[('foo', '<u4'), ('bar', '<f8')])
In [51]: a.shape
Out[51]: (2,)
In [52]: b.shape
Out[52]: (3,)
```

`a,b` are 1d, so concatenate on (default) axis 0 works:

```
In [53]: np.concatenate((a,b))
Out[53]: 
array([(2, 1.1), (3, 2.2), (4, 3.3), (5, 4.4), (6, 5.5)],
      dtype=[('foo', '<u4'), ('bar', '<f8')])
```

`vstack` makes the (1,2) and (1,3) and tries to join on the size 1, resulting the error.  It is quite explicit about the problem dimensions.

The special `dtype` isn't the problem - except that you were viewing the arrays as being 2d.

Answer (score 1):

Use [np.concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
import numpy as np

myType = np.dtype([
    ('foo', 'u4'),
    ('bar', 'f8')
])

a = np.array([(2, 1.1), (3, 2.2)], dtype=myType)
b = np.array([(4, 3.3), (5, 4.4), (6, 5.5)], dtype=myType)

result = np.concatenate((a, b))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[(2, 1.1) (3, 2.2) (4, 3.3) (5, 4.4) (6, 5.5)]
```

or [np.hstack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
result = np.hstack((a, b))
```